# After a failed Room migration, Android Studio keeps crashing, and previous versions have also stopped working

Tags: android, crash, android-room-migration

I conducted a simple Room auto-migration test in my app. However, I noticed that there was no JSON file corresponding to version 1. In response, I commented out all the new columns and changes in the code and then ran the app, but it crashed.

I attempted to reopen previously saved files that hadn't undergone any migrations. These versions had worked perfectly before. However, upon opening and running them on the same emulator as before, they also crashed.

I tried clearing the cache of the app in the emulator, but there was no change.
the method .fallbacktodestructivemigration didn't work as well.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it and make your app functional again?